# Non-interactive installation of an additional Python environment on a computer which already has Python installed

Tags: python, windows, windows-installer

I'm working on a deployment tool which will build a python environment with a number of dependancies pre-installed. [According to the documentation on Python's web-site](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.4/msi/#automated) I should be able to do something like this:

```
msiexec.exe /i python_installer\python-2.4.4.msi TARGETDIR=c:\temp\install\fooX
```

However in the case where that version of Python is already installed on the system (in the regular C:\Python24 location) this command-line will attempt to repair the existing installation. It will not create a new installation in the TARGETDIR.

Does anybody know of additional command-line arguments which will help me achieve the following:

- I want the installation to block until the installation is complete. That way I can start the next process of my environment build once the current process has ended.
- I want the installation to always install to the TARGETDIR regardless of whether a valid Python installation exists elsewhere.

FYI, I'm using Python 2.4.4 on Windows XP 32bit.

UPDATE1: We have a solution to the "awlays installing problem", I just need a way to make the program block until completed. If I do /qn the process spawns a background process and terminates immediatly. I've always wondered why so many Windows tools work this way - it makes command line scripting impossible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the `/a` instead of `/i` flag:

From msiexec help:

```
/a <Product.msi>
    Administrative install - Installs a product on the network
```

Another option to consider is `/qn`:

```
/q[n|b|r|f]
    Sets user interface level
    n - No UI
```

You can get to the help window of msiexec by executing only `msiexec` without parameters.

Comment: /a solves the problem of isntalling regardless of whether a valid Python install exists. I just need a way to force the process to block until the installation has finished.

Comment: I noticed that too, msiexec instanstly returns to prompt, even when install is not finished.

Comment: I think I might cheat by using a zip of the project. Scripting on windows is just a pain.

Comment: Wait, I just spotted this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2005/11/15/493236.aspx